# Форум на ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forum, .net

Здравствуйте, стоит задача сделать форум на сайте, есть 2 пути:

1. самому написать
2. взять готовый движок

Существует ли, какое-нибудь легковесное решение этой задачи или надо писать самому? P.S если существует, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: [пара примеров](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=mvc%20forum&sortBy=Relevance&licenses=|)

Comment: Писать самому форум (если со всеми фичами) задача на полгода(если вы тру), год (если не особо) и год+ если начинающий.

Судя по тому что у вас возник такой вопрос - в вашем случае это год+

PS: конечно если речь не о форуме "с ограниченым функционалом"

Comment: если использовать web forms authentication + разделы + темы + сообщения - разделение прав доступа - личка - голосования - репутация и всё это без ajax плюшек, то можно сделать достаточно быстро

Comment: Видимо у нас с вами разное представление о том что такое форум.

(аякс плюшки тут вообще не причем)

Comment: я как раз и описал "форум с ограниченым функционалом", опишите свой вариант.


аякс плюшка: отправка\обновление\удаления сообщений без перезагрузки страницы - очень удобна!

Comment: Средний дев сделает средний форум без особых наворотов за 2-3 месяца без проблем, при условии конечно, что он будет работать хотя бы по 160 часов в месяц. Если же это студент и планирует работать после ВУЗа, то такой форум может делаться годами.

Comment: Можно и самому написать, если функциональности мало. Если много, то надо искать уже в соответствиями с требованиями.

Answer (score 0):

Могу порекомендовать движок opensource MVC: http://mesoboard.com/

Пример реализации: http://www.dunaydv.ru/

Answer (score 0):

Я разворачивал [MvcForum](http://www.mvcforum.com/). Содержит весь минимальный функционал. Код понятен и вполне расширяем.